Vector space topologies stronger than the strongest locally convex topology
Every real vector space has the strongest locally convex topology, which is the topology generated by all the convex sets whose intersection with every line is an open interval.
What about topologies that are not necessarily locally convex?

Are there real topological vector spaces whose topologies are stronger (finer) than the strongest locally convex topology on that space?

If yes, does every real vector space have the strongest vector space topology (among all the topologies that make it a TVS)?

If yes, is there a simple characterization of some system of basic open neighborhoods in this strongest topology?




Yes, because the supremum of vector space topologies is again a vector space topology. 1. Yes, the finest vector space topology on an uncountable sum $X=\bigoplus\limits_{i\in I}\mathbb R$ making all inclusions $\mathbb R\to X$ continuous is not locally convex and hence strictly finer than the strongest locally convex topology on $X$: The ball with radius $1$ around $0$ of the translation invariant metric $d(x.y)=\sum\limits_{i\in I} \sqrt{|x_i-y_i|}$ does not contain a convex neighbourhood of $0$.


@Jochen, thanks, I'll need to think more about (1). About (2), I do not see immediately what this topology looks like and why this ball of radius $1$ is a neighborhood of $\mathbf{0}$. I've added a third question.

The answers to your questions and the details of the example I mentioned can be found in the book Topological Vector spaces - The Theory Without Convexity Conditions of Adam, Ernst, and Keim freely available here: https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/BFb0068514
